# Multiple feature file launching with single browser instance in Specflow

Tags: bdd, xunit, specflow

When I am running my test solution, single browser is getting launched but it is running two feature file simultaneously due to which test cases are failing. One step it is taking from one feature file and other from other feature file.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have enough information to provide you an answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comment left on your question, I think I may have enough context to answer you.

You describe feature files that are sharing steps and concerns about multiple browser instances. This tells me that your various step files might each be containing a browser instance.

What you're likely looking to do instead is to use a SpecFlow Context -- SpecFlow provides it own `ScenarioContext` object you can use, or you can create your own context and inject it.

Some links that might help:

- SpecFlow docs on sharing data between bindings, which explains about ScenarioContext and FeatureContext:
  https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings.html
- Here's an article on using SpecFlow with Selenium and the Page Object Model: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/ui-automation/Selenium-with-Page-Object-Pattern.html
- The SpecFlow YouTube channel will likely be helpful as it's full of experts walking through these sort of examples: https://www.youtube.com/c/SpecFlowBDD/videos

  - Here's the first video in a 5 part series on how to automate a web application with Selenium and SpecFlow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1dAogvWVh8

---

Based on your question, it's also possible that your issue could be that you *want* things to run in parallel, but have the problem of your tests being dependent on one another or running in a certain order. This will be a bit more complex to solve.

I strongly suggest you treat your tests so that they can be run in isolation. You may need to add separate data to a database, or operate your tests so that they're not touching the same thing. This takes more work, but is more than worth it, because it will enable better maintainability and reliability of your tests and also ensure they can run in parallel successfully.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the help!! I want feature files to run separately and in sequential manner. I have created end to end test cases so no dependency. But my features files are launching browser at same time, making the tests fail.